# Unable to connect hive with kafka

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, docker-compose, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have a project that consist of training a model then storing the result of using the best model in hive using kafka Topic.

I tried various configuration and solution out there but in vain

This is the docker-compose file used.

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:1.1.0-hadoop2.8-java8
    container_name: namenode
    volumes:
      - namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
      - ./infra/zeppelin/examples:/opt/sansa-examples
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    ports:
      - "50070:50070"
      - "8020:8020"
      - "8081:8081"

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:1.1.0-hadoop2.8-java8
    container_name: datanode
    volumes:
      - datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    links:
      - namenode

  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:2.1.0-hadoop2.8-hive-java8
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8090:800"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
      - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=localhost
    depends_on:
      - namenode
      - datanode
    links:
      - namenode
      - datanode

  spark-worker:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:2.1.0-hadoop2.8-hive-java8
    container_name: spark-worker
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
    environment:
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
      - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=localhost
    links:
      - spark-master

  hue:
    image: bde2020/hdfs-filebrowser:3.11
    container_name: hue
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    environment:
      - NAMENODE_HOST=namenode
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
    links:
      - spark-master

  zeppelin:
    image: bde2020/zeppelin:0.0.1-zeppelin-0.7.1-hadoop-2.8.0-spark-2.1.0
    container_name: zeppelin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./data:/opt/zeppelin/data
  #    - ./infra/zeppelin/conf:/opt/zeppelin/conf
      - ./infra/zeppelin/logs:/opt/zeppelin/logs
      - ./infra/zeppelin/notebooks:/opt/zeppelin/notebook
      - ./infra/zeppelin/examples:/opt/sansa-examples
    environment:
      CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS: "hdfs://namenode:8020"
      SPARK_MASTER: "spark://spark-master:7077"
      MASTER: "spark://spark-master:7077"
      SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS: "--jars /opt/sansa-examples/jars/sansa-examples-spark.jar --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
    links:
      - spark-master

  hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive
    container_name: hive-server
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      - "HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL=jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
    links:
      - namenode
      - hive-metastore
    ports:
      - 10000:10000

  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql
    container_name: hive-metastore-postgresql

  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive
    container_name: hive-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./infra/hadoop/hadoop-hive.env
    links:
      - namenode
      - hive-metastore-postgresql
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    ports:
      - 9083:9083

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    volumes:
      - zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    links:
      - zookeeper
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper  
      
  # kafka:
  #   image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
  #   container_name: kafka
  #   ports:
  #     - 9092:9092
  #   environment:
  #     KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  #     KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
  #     KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
  #     KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  #     KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  #     KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
  #   volumes:
  #     - kafka:/var/lib/kafka
  #   links:
  #     - zookeeper
  #   depends_on:
  #     - zookeeper

  nifi:
    image: xemuliam/nifi
    container_name: nifi
    ports:
      - 5080:5080
      - 5443:8443
      - 5081:5081
## for scaling we have to do this
#      - 8080
    links:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - ./infra/nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/conf
      - ./infra/nifi/logs:/opt/nifi/logs
      - ./data:/opt/datafiles
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/flowfile_repository
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/database_repository
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/content_repository
      - nifi:/opt/nifi/provenance_repository
    environment:
      ZK_NODES_LIST: zookeeper
      IS_CLUSTER_NODE: 1
      ELECTION_TIME: 1 min

volumes:
  namenode:
  datanode:
  zookeeper:
  kafka:
  nifi:
```

And this is the hadoop environement

```
HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL=jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore-postgresql/metastore
HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionDriverName=org.postgresql.Driver
HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionUserName=hive
HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionPassword=hive
HIVE_SITE_CONF_datanucleus_autoCreateSchema=false
HIVE_SITE_CONF_hive_metastore_uris=thrift://hive-metastore:9083
HIVE_SITE_CONF_hive_fetch_task_conversion=none

CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_hosts=*
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_groups=*

HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true
HDFS_CONF_dfs_permissions_enabled=false

YARN_CONF_yarn_log___aggregation___enable=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_recovery_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_store_class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_fs_state___store_uri=/rmstate
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_remote___app___log___dir=/app-logs
YARN_CONF_yarn_log_server_url=http://historyserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_generic___application___history_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_system___metrics___publisher_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_hostname=resourcemanager
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_hostname=historyserver
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_address=resourcemanager:8032
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_address=resourcemanager:8030
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_resource__tracker_address=resourcemanager:8031
```

My version of Hadoop is : 2.7.4
My version of Hive is : 2.3.2

This is the configuration of the interpeter Hive within zeppelin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDlbk.png)

And this is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5q1X.png)

Comment: Unrelated to the error - `hive-server:9092` isn't the correct address. You need to use `kafka:9092`. And you need to fix `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME` to be `kafka`. The Confluent image is correctly defined, so it's unclear why you've commented it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Kafka handler JAR to Hiveserver2 container classpath, as that's what's really executing the query, not Zeppelin.

The only way to do that, would be to mount a volume in your Compose file, under the path Hive uses to read libraries.

Otherwise, just use Spark Structured Streaming, or your Nifi container instead, to write to Kafka. Only metadata is stored "in Hive". The real data is stored in Kafka. Plus, I'm not so sure Cloudera maintains the Hive Kafka Handler, and it doesn't appear to be published to Maven Central, either.